# cant add border style in table (phpword)

Tags: php, css, phpword

i am trying to add border in my table inside html. below is my code

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$html = "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>John</td></tr>
</table>";
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html );
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

i have assigned a border of 1 but it didnt work. there is no border in my table

it event doesnt work by adding styling. please help

Answer (score 0):

tried run your code with minimal changes and all work)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html;

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$html = "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>John</td></tr>
</table>";
Html::addHtml($section, $html);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5CRU.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this case use inline CSS. This how you should do it:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html;

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$html = "<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
<tr>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>John</td></tr>
</table>";
Html::addHtml($section, $html);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```